# Updating master dictionary with function output without using dictionary update

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my following code

```
import os 
import string

#(Function A) - that will take in string as input and update the master dictionary 
def counter(file):
    word_counter = dict()
    f = open(file, "rt")
    words = f.read().split()
    words= filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), words)
        
    for word in words:
        if word in word_counter:
            word_counter[word] += 1
        else:
            word_counter[word] = 1
    
    return word_counter
    
# outside of Function       
master = dict()

filelist=[os.path.join('medline',f) for f in os.listdir('medline')]
for file in filelist:
    master.update(counter(file))

#Function B - Passed the mass dictionary A and outputed the top 3 words

def sort_dict(A):
    remove_duplicate = []
    new_list = dict()
    for key, val in A.items():
        if val not in remove_duplicate:
            remove_duplicate.append(val)
            new_list[key] = val

    new_list = sorted(new_list.items(), key = lambda word_counter: word_counter[1], reverse = True)
    print (f'Top 3 words for the master dictionary:', new_list[:3])

sort_dict(master)
```

The problem is I can't use the update function (rule of the puzzle).

I need to update  a master dictionary that is outside these functions with the output dictionary generated from each file in the directory that I iterate through (Function A). I'm only allowed to use those modules and I can't convert it to a list to append them and then make a dictionary out of those. I am really stuck on this problem and am not sure how to get the output I get from function A into a dictionary I can use for Function B without breaking the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't described the actual requirements, but I suspect you want the word count across all files. Your use of `update()` will replace a word count with its count from the next file containing the word, and you'll end up with each word only being counted from its last file.

You need to add the count from the current file to the value that's already in the dictionary.

```
for file in filelist:
    for key, val in counter(file).items():
        master[key] = master.get(key, 0) + val
```

You can also do this in the `counter()` function itself, rather than returning a dictionary.

```
def counter(file):
    f = open(file, "rt")
    words = f.read().split()
    words= filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), words)
        
    for word in words:
        master[word] = master.get(word, 0) + 1
```

Instead of using `if key in master:` you can use `master.get()` with a default value.

Comment: I *suspect* that the "puzzle" is expecting the user to mutate the global `master` dict.

Comment: Isn't that what this does?

Comment: I mean fro within `counter` otherwise I cannot fathom some arbitrary ristriction like "you can't use `master.update`".

Comment: Now that I think of it, I suspect he's supposed to combine the counts across all the files. This will just get the counts from the last file that contains each word.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've tried the global method and it doesn't work

Comment: @Barmar that is exactly what I am trying to do! Thanks, man! I'm a newbie with python